# 404 page shown as source when debug=true in web.config (chrome and ff, not in edge)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

in my mvc app when I get a request for a nonexistent route, 
I clear the sever error and redirect to my ErrorController (code in 
 Global.asax.cs Application_Error):

```
Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

Server.ClearError();

var routeData = new RouteData();
routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
routeData.Values.Add("action", "HttpError404");

IController errorController = new ErrorController();
errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(
     new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
```

and the action returns a view:

```
public ActionResult HttpError404(Exception error)
{
    Response.StatusCode = 404;

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return Content("404 not found");
    }

    return View();
}
```

the problem is that when there is `compilation debug="true"` in web.config in chrome and ff (not in edge) the 404 page is shown as source (plain html)

Comment: `compilation` has nothing to do with this ...check if browser link is enabled for you , Disable and check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`compilation` has nothing to do with something that is specific to browsers.

However from your implementation it seems that browser link is causing this issue .

You can disable `browser link` and check if that works ,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link#disabling